# MOD_REWRITE all requests to subdirectory 403 problems

Tags: php, angularjs, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im working within MVC style framework with a typical apache mod_rewrite,

**Directory Structure**

- ROOT

  - .htaccess
  - Application

    - Controllers
    - Assets
  - Public

    - js
    - css
    - .htaccess
  - System

In the ROOT directory of my project I have a .htaccess sending all calls to the public folder except files and directories, in the public folder I then have another .htaccess that sends all calls to the index.php except files and directories both are at the bottom.

Now I keep all bower components in the application folder and during development and then minified and compressed and concat etc into the public directory for release.

This means that during release I only have to include one script src="/js/mylongscript.js"

How ever during development I wanted to be able to access the untouched code in the application directory which i thought would work as had already put the rules in place, and it does when I type the url to the file in the browser.

But when included as a src="application/assets/angular.js" I keep getting a 403 permission error.

I have tried the following src formats

```
<script src="http://kratos.io/application/assets/angular.js"></script>
<script src="application/assets/angular.js"></script>
```

But this works to the minified in the public dir

```
<script src="http://kratos.io/js/longscript.js"></script>
<script src="js/longscript.js"></script>
```

MY ROOT .htaccess - Directs all calls to the public folder

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?kratos.io$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?kratos.io$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ public/$1 [L]
```

My PUBLIC .htaccess

```
 RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

**Is this a problem with my rewrite rule ? . . . Do I need another ? . . . How comes it works when types in as a url but not when included as a script src? . .  Do I need an exception for the application/assets folder ? or a rule to jump back up from public directory to the ROOT ?**

I have Read this >> http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase

and this >> http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

and been searching google for the last 3 hours but without knowing exactly what im doing wrong I don't know how to fix it

NOTE Eventaully angular scripts and components would be in the application folder aswell and accessed from the public directory so this would also stop that from working . . .

**Update**

Since trying the first answer given I got the error

```
[Wed Apr 08 16:05:18.484189 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 8148:tid 964] [client 127.0.0.1:63826] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/Apache24, referer: http://kratos.io/
```

So Just incase my vhost configuration using wamp

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@kratos.io
    ServerName kratos.io
    ServerAlias www.kratos.io
    DocumentRoot "r:\Server\vhosts\kratos"
        <Directory "r:\Server\vhosts\kratos">
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: And you -1 for that ?

Comment: I did not downvote. Someone else did.

Answer (score 0):

If you want direct access to files under `/Application` directory then change your root .htaccess to this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?kratos\.io$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(public|Application)/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Tried the above and got 403 to everything due to Options -Indexes so removed that and just got blank page checked apache logs and got this [Wed Apr 08 16:05:18.484189 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 8148:tid 964] [client 127.0.0.1:63826] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/Apache24, referer: http://kratos.io/ as far as I know there is nothing wrong with my vhost setup .

Comment: just incase ill update my question with the vhost in it  . . .and when i altered my original code changing just the RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(public|Application)/ [NC] line got 403 to angular js still

Comment: No luck still 403 and as far as I knew  require all granted is needed for apache 2.4 + now see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html

Comment: No luck the part i dont understand is if i visit http://kratos.io/application/assets/angular.js it all works its only when being included as a src when all hell breaks loose except for that I get 200 ok if url is used to get to it so i knw its there . . how I take a call thats landed in the public dir and if it matches application/* send it back to root . . . or how comes the !-f or !-d are not working

Comment: If I include on the page as follows

    <script src="http://kratos.io/application/assets/vendor/js/angular/angular.js"></script>

I get a 403 Forbidden Response https://www.dropbox.com/s/bukiyrmfsop5p18/Screenshot%20%2810%29.png?dl=0

Comment: But if I just visit the same script by typing the url in the address bar of the browser it works and I see the script https://www.dropbox.com/s/jt3h60qnx9dref2/Screenshot%20%2811%29.png?dl=0

Comment: how does it appear to be some other issue when im getting a 403 (Forbidden) header

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - - [08/Apr/2015:18:54:55 +0100] "GET /application/assets/vendor/js/angular/angular.js HTTP/1.1" 403 333

Comment: That was from src and this is from url 127.0.0.1 - - [08/Apr/2015:19:00:45 +0100] "GET /application/assets/vendor/js/angular/angular.js HTTP/1.1" 200 960560 im clearly getting a 200 ok from url but 403 from src as the apache logs state

Comment: Is there some `HTTP_REFERER` based rule somewhere? I think at this stage you will need to enable `RewriteLog` to debug it further.

Comment: Yes . . .yes there was should have mentioned have added answer

Comment: Glad that it was found but you should not add a new answer for this. Since my answer and a long followup has resolved your problem you should mark this answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Completely out of scope of what I thought the problem was....**

Apologies !!

What I didn't mention is the rest of the .htaccess file in the ROOT directory.

It has extras to protect against hacks and attacks . . One thing I protect against is common fingerprint attacks the code below is similar to that used on other frameworks

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteRule ^images/stories/([^/]+/)*([^/.]+\.)+(jp(e?g|2)?|png|gif|bmp|css|js|swf|ico)$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?kratos.io\.com [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
 RewriteRule \.(jp(e?g|2)?|png|gif|bmp|css|js|swf|ico)$ - [F]
</IfModule>
```

Note the error

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?kratos.io\.com [NC]
```

Correct the line to

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?kratos\.io [NC]
```

And it no longer thinks i'm trying to attack the file as my url in the script tag matches the Condition.